# Sencha architect use Ext.ux.ToolbarDroppable

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I'm looking for the Ext.ux.ToolbarDroppable plugin which allow to drag/drop column onto a toolbar for multisort as we can see in the following multi sort example :

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#multi-sort-grid

How to use it in Sencha architect (version 2.2.2) ?

Comment: Finaly i did extend a toolbar and adapted the sample code to make it work with any grid on which you add this toolbar. I will share my code asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code :

https://gist.github.com/SneakyBobito/5625682

You have to create a new toolbar in Architect. Then you have to override this toolbar with the code i gave (think to replace the two first lines).

Finally add the toolbar to a grid (not into a panel, think to ad it to the grid, because i use .up('grid')  in the code).